# Regular expression '\w+' is supposed to return only words in english, but it is working differently

Tags: python, regex

```
s = 'ಆತಂಕವಾದಿಗಳಿಗೆ ವಿಶೇಷ ರಕ್ಷಣೆ ನೀಡುತ್ತದೆ, 24 ಕ್ಕೂ ಹೆಚ್ಚು ಹಿಂದೂ ಕಾರ್ಯಕರ್ತರ ಹತ್ಯೆಯಾದರೂ I am working on this'
words = re.findall(r'\w+',s)
print(words)
```

I expected the above code to return only english words, but i am getting something as below.

```
['ಆತ', 'ಕವ', 'ದ', 'ಗಳ', 'ಗ', 'ವ', 'ಶ', 'ಷ', 'ರಕ', 'ಷಣ', 'ನ', 'ಡ', 'ತ', 'ತದ',
    '24', 'ಕ', 'ಕ', 'ಹ', 'ಚ', 'ಚ', 'ಹ', 'ದ', 'ಕ', 'ರ', 'ಯಕರ', 'ತರ', 'ಹತ', 'ಯ',
    'ಯ', 'ದರ', 'I', 'am', 'working', 'on', 'this']
```

Could someone explain how this is working?

Comment: Note to everyone: The OP's code appears [to be working in this demo](https://rextester.com/KQWP73350).  I can only speculate that there is some weird encoding issue happening.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It looks like the demo you linked uses Python 2 but I'm guessing Amarnath is using Python 3, which does exhibit the problem. Amarnath, can you please edit the question to confirm which version of Python you're using?

Comment: "I expected the above code to return only english words" - *why*?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+',s, re.ASCII)` ?

Comment: `words = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]','',s)` sub works fine but its different in findall not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you expected `\w+` to only match English words. It doesn't even do that in ASCII mode. It matches any sequence of `\w` characters, and the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) describe the actual behavior of `\w`:

> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>   Matches Unicode word characters; this includes **most characters that can be part of a word in any language**, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
>   Matches characters considered alphanumeric in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]. If the LOCALE flag is used, matches characters considered alphanumeric in the current locale and the underscore.

The docs unfortunately don't get any more specific than that, but `\w` definitely isn't restricted to English.

If you wanted `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you can write out your intended character class explicitly, or you can use the `re.ASCII` flag. If you wanted `[a-zA-Z]`, write that out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your observations, [see the demo](https://rextester.com/KQWP73350).  Perhaps there is some encoding issue on your end, which is why `\w` is picking up on Tamil characters.  But, one workaround you could use here would be to just explicitly spell out of what the character class `\w` actually consists:

```
words = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9_]+', s)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+',s)
```

The reason `\w+` doesn't pick up what you want is that it's missing the Unicode flag. The other answers here ignore encoding by simply saying which specific letters they are looking for

> **\w**
>
> **When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore**; this is equivalent to the
>   set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus
>   whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current
>   locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus
>   whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

That is why.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea but a little backwards; actually, the problem appears to be that `\w` in the OP's code sample is picking up _more_ than just `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I believe the difference is that what you're saying here applies to Python 2, but I suspect the code in the question is meant to run with Python 3.

Comment: Guess you're right.. though it could just be a localization issue, as stated above.. May require more thorough investigating.

Comment: Well, I can't rule it out, but I'm considerably more confident that it's a 2 vs 3 issue given that running the OP's code sample in Python 3 reproduces their issue but running it in Python 2 does not, and that your quote, which comes from the Python 2 documentation, describes the opposite behavior of what the OP is seeing, i.e. precisely what would happen if you run their code sample under Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as given below to know why it is printing like that:

```
s = u'ಆತಂಕವಾದಿಗಳಿಗೆ ವಿಶೇಷ ರಕ್ಷಣೆ ನೀಡುತ್ತದೆ, 24 ಕ್ಕೂ ಹೆಚ್ಚು ಹಿಂದೂ ಕಾರ್ಯಕರ್ತರ ಹತ್ಯೆಯಾದರೂ I am 
working on this'
words = re.findall(r'\w+',s)
print(words)


for letter in s:
    print(letter)
```

OUTPUT

```
['ಆತ', 'ಕವ', 'ದ', 'ಗಳ', 'ಗ', 'ವ', 'ಶ', 'ಷ', 'ರಕ', 'ಷಣ', 'ನ', 'ಡ', 'ತ', 'ತದ', '24', 'ಕ', 'ಕ', 'ಹ', 'ಚ', 'ಚ', 'ಹ', 'ದ', 'ಕ', 'ರ', 'ಯಕರ', 'ತರ', 'ಹತ', 'ಯ', 'ಯ', 'ದರ', 'I', 'am', 'working', 'on', 'this']
ಆ
ತ
ಂ 
ಕ
ವ
ಾ  
ದ

ಗ
ಳ

ಗ


ವ

ಶ
ೇ
ಷ

ರ
ಕ

ಷ
ಣ


ನ
ೀ
ಡ
ು
ತ

ತ
ದ

,

2
4

ಕ

ಕ
ೂ

ಹ

ಚ

ಚ
ು

ಹ

ಂ
ದ
ೂ

ಕ
ಾ
ರ

ಯ
ಕ
ರ

ತ
ರ

ಹ
ತ

ಯ

ಯ
ಾ
ದ
ರ
ೂ

I

a
m

w
o
r
k
i
n
g

o
n

t
h
i
s
```

Those circles are kind of spaces [ As understood by the code ]

Answer (score 0):

Look at @itzMEonTV's suggestion:

```
In [46]: rex=re.compile(r'\w+')                                                                                               
In [47]: rex                                                                                                                  
Out[47]: re.compile(r'\w+', re.UNICODE)
```